# Chineese help needed. Can't read letters off PCB board

Tags: translation

I bought a relay and I have Chinese alphabets written over it.
I am not sure what it reads. 
Quick answers appreciated, 
Here is the image:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

From left to right:

NO (normal open); 
common port; 
NC (normal close)